# How to sort my todo's in org-agenda based on scheduled date?

Tags: org-mode

I have a problem with my org-agendas. I have tried to sort my todo's
in each agenda view after their scheduled date, but that does not
function. I use the following code:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
     ("d" "daily "(
        (tags-todo "TODO={TODO}+SCHEDULED<=\"<today>\"+PRIORITY={B} "  (
        (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(scheduled-down))
        ))
  ))))
```

The todo's does not get sorted after scheduled date, but are listen totally unrelated to it. Can anybody tell me why my code does not sort after scheduled date?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suggest grepping the source code for `"org-add-props txt props"` to determine whether text properties are added to the relevant sections to support sorting by the desired criteria.  I fixed this in my own custom setup, but never took the time to submit a patch.  I filed a bug-report and was advised that fixes were in the pipeline, but I don't know when or if those fixes were ever implemented.  In short, if there are no text properties that have the relevant criteria for sorting, then no sorting will occur.  You should try using the most recent version of `org-mode`.